# Cannot retrieve values from JS object using hash syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm seeing strange behavior when accessing properties from a JS object via the [] operator.

I have 3 columns in a table **'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'**. My JS object has a property called Attributes, which is a hashtable that looks like **{attr1: 'val', attr2: 'val', attr3: 'val'}**

The following contrived code works fine

```
function onRowDataBound(e) {
    var attributes = e.dataItem.Attributes;
    var keys = {0: 'attr1', 1: 'attr2', 2: 'attr3'};
    for (var key in keys) {
        var keyVal = keys[key];
        var attribute = attributes[keyVal];
        if (attribute != undefined) {
            e.row.cells[key].innerText = attribute;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the following code, where I'm dynamically building the keys object; **attribute** is always undefined.

```
function getKeys() {
    var keys = {};
    $('#Equipment thead th').each(function() {
        keys[this.cellIndex] = this.innerText;
    });
    return keys;
}

function onRowDataBound(e) {
    var attributes = e.dataItem.Attributes;
    var keys = getKeys();
    for (var key in keys) {
        var keyVal = keys[key];
        var attribute = attributes[keyVal];
        if (attribute != undefined) {
            e.row.cells[key].innerText = attribute;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.innerText` is a dangerous monkey.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery anyway, use `.text()` instead of `innerText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a trim of the value:

```
$('#Equipment thead th').each(function() {
    keys[this.cellIndex] = jQuery.trim(this.innerText);
});
```

Do you know what exactly `keyVal` contains at each iteration?

Comment: I was just going to post that this was indeed the problem. Found it while troubleshooting a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var keys = {};
$("#Equipment thead th").each(function (i, e) {
  keys[i] = $(this).html();
});
```

Does that get you what you want?